# SSIS Package won't do anything when Run through SQL Server Job

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-job

I have a simple SSIS Package, which has
a Excute SQL Task control on the Control Flow, which fetches some value from the database

In the DataFlow, am using a Script Component, which based on values given by 'Excute SQL Task', does this:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {

        try
        {

            string loginURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + Variables.ProjectAddress + "&sensor=true";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string downloadString = client.DownloadString(loginURL);
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(downloadString);

    ///// setting output buffer variables
         }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {

       }
}
```

so basically am requesting a web service for latitude and longitude inside the package.
The retrieved values are then updated into the database:

Everything works fine, when I run the package from the Visual Studio SSIS project console.
But when I try to run the package through a SQL Server 2008 R2 Job, nothing happens. Job Executes successfully but no rows are updated(or inserted).

I tried importing the package into SQL MSDB and setting the protection level to all the items in the dropdown one by one as given [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440760%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
...and then running this imported package from SQL Job. Still...nothing happened.

Does anyone know whats wrong?? How do I deal with following facts:

1. It has to do with permission of the sql user to make a web service request. How do I configure that out?

2.it has to do with the configuration file of imported ssis package. What should I look for?

Help me out please:
I hope I have given all the required info to look into the problem

Answer (score 1):

is the job on an SQL Server Instance on your computer? I ask because it may be firewall or permission issues from the SQL Server to the computer you have the web service.

Also I advise removing that try catch and enabling package configurations so you can see if it is trowing an error

Regarding protection level, if you are using EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey the package wont load the database sensitive information (login and password) unless it is on the computer you developed it. Same thing applies to EncryptAllWithUserKey but in this case it wont even open the package